# Generate .so library for use on Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, .so

I have compiled a C++ file, but do not meet the JNI format.

How can I use a .so library generated from a C++ file for different CPU architecture in Android?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Android NDK. Do you need a link? It is integrated in Android Studio 2.3. Start with some sample apps to get used to this tool.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex Cohn said to use C/C++ code in android you need Android NDK. You can download Android NDK directly from Android studio using the SDK Manager.
  The steps needed to download NDK and use Cmake or ndkBuild to build native library of your c++ code.

1) In Android studio menu bar press on Tools->Android->Android->SDK Manager. And download cmake, LLDB and NDK.
[image]
2)If you downloaded the NDK and cmake when you create a new project tick the include button but this button is found in android studio 2.2 and above[image].